# Defining a discrete sequence along an arbitrary time axis

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, time-domain

I need to compute the output of the system y[n] = x[−n].  x[n] is of length 1 : 26866, and the y[n] output axis has the same length and goes from -12850 : 13975.
variables:
x[n] = x1,
output axis y[n] = nx,
output sequence = xt
Difficulty is when I encounter the 0 and negative part of the new (reversed) index.  I'm not sure where to get values of x1 that correspond to the negative, new indices.  Here is the code I've composed so far:

```
xt = zeros(size(nx)); %define ouput sequence
for nn = 1:length(nx) %convert output axis with negative values to positive sequence
    indx = -nx(nn);  % New index (reversed nx axis)
    if indx > 0 %Indices are positive, so xt takes values of the last x1 indices, until index of 0
        xt(nn) = xt(nn) + x1(indx);
    elseif indx <= 0
        xt(nn) = ; %Here I'm lost
    end       
end
 xt
```

Thank you for your time,
Justin Gilmore

Answer (score 0):

Matlab arrays always start at index 1, so technically you can't represent an array from indexed from -12850 : 13975 : 13975 in Matlab directly.

Most people work around this by simply keeping manually track of an index offset. Something like

```
yOffset = -12850 +1;  % offset
tmp = y(yOffset + nn); % access y() starting at -12850
```

The time reversal is simple enough

```
y = flip(x);
```